# Не могу создать пользователя tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, users

Ошибка при развертывании: Отсутствуют права доступа к серверу Tomcat. Введите правильное имя пользователя и пароль для роли "manager-script" в средстве настройки Tomcat в менеджере серверов.
Для получения подробных сведений см. протокол сервера.

В tomcat-users.xml,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">

<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="root" password="root" roles="manager-script"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Где лежит ваш tomcat-users.xml? И что там в протоколе сервера, смотрели?

Comment: /var/lib/tomcat8/conf